# Verify failing with default / expected parameters

Tags: c#, moq

Can anyone help with this following code, which is failing. From what I can see I can't tell why the expected params I'm listing will not cause the method to fire.

Test code:

```
Mock<ExpiryNotifier> target = new Mock<ExpiryNotifier>();
Mock<MailServiceWrapper> mailMock = new Mock<MailServiceWrapper>();
mailMock.Verify(
    m => m.SendMail(
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string[]>(),
        It.IsAny<string[]>(),
        It.IsAny<string[]>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<string[]>()
    ), 
    Times.Exactly(1)
);
target.Setup(t => t.getMailService()).Returns(mailMock.Object);
target.Object.notify();
```

The actual code:

```
public virtual MailServiceWrapper getMailService()
{
    MailServiceWrapper MailService = new MailServiceWrapper();
    return MailService;
}

public string notify()
{
    string feed = loadFeed();
    MailServiceWrapper MailService = getMailService();
    MailService.SendMail(
                "sysmail.blah.net",
                "blah@blah.com",
                new string[] {"blah@blah.com"},
                new string[] { },
                new string[] { },
                "blah blah",
                "This is a blah blah email",
                new string[] { }
            );
}
```

method signature:

```
public virtual string SendMail(string server, string from, string[] to, string[] ccs, string[] bccs, string title, string body, string[] attachments)
```

Comment: So are you actually *using* `mailMock`? What error do you get? It would help if you'd post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Thanks edited orig post with more code.

Comment: You're verifying the expectation before you've called `notify`.  As an aside, it would probably be more sensible to inject your service via the constructor then to have to override a method that creates it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to verify/assert after you've executed your test:

```
// Arrange
Mock<ExpiryNotifier> target = new Mock<ExpiryNotifier>();
Mock<MailServiceWrapper> mailMock = new Mock<MailServiceWrapper>();
target.Setup(t => t.getMailService()).Returns(mailMock.Object);

// Act
target.Object.notify();

// Assert
mailMock.Verify(
            m => m.SendMail(
                It.IsAny<string>(),
                It.IsAny<string>(),
                It.IsAny<string[]>(),
                It.IsAny<string[]>(),
                It.IsAny<string[]>(),
                It.IsAny<string>(),
                It.IsAny<string>(),
                It.IsAny<string[]>()
            ), 
            Times.Exactly(1)
        );
```

Comment: Ah OK thanks - that works! This works differently to what I'm used to with PHPUnit - which sets all mock objects up with their canned return values **before** the execution of any code that subsequently calls it.

Comment: Didn't know about how PHPUnit works. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This is slightly different as you're not setting up canned return values, you're checking 'was this called'.  `Setup` happens in the 'arrange' phase, `Verify` happens in the 'assert' phase.

Answer (score 0):

`.Verify()` is a method that's called *after* the fact in order to, indeed, *verify* that the method you're suggesting *was* called.